# How to do External Redirection With Parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, laravel

How do I do an external redirection and get the 'URL-String' after .aspx?

```
http://www.sample.com/folder1/filename.aspx/title
```

to

```
http://www.sample.com/folder1/filename/title
```

I have done the following

```
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z0-9]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.aspx
#RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

But it returns wrong URL

```
http://www.sample.com/folder1
```

Appreciate your kind advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+)\.aspx(\S*)
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/([^/.]+)/?$ /$1.aspx/$2 [L]
```

Comment: Can help to explain the 3rd line ?
What is \S ? I used (.*) but it returns with http header.

Comment: `\S*` is used to capture string until a space is matched. `.*` will match everything